# Webservices vs. Message Queues?

Tags: python, django, web-services, message-queue

What are the implications of using webservices or message queues in an application?

In my case, I need to connect a Django web application with a python application, and I need two way communication between these applications. Sometimes the web app sends request to the python app to activate a few hardware devices, and sometimes the python app needs to be generally queried to obtain data.

The issue my entire application depends on instantaneous data received or sent to the python core application, so I cannot afford to waste system resources on querying everytime. I need to use something like a listener/receiver to send/receive data, without manually triggering a query every few seconds.

I am using Django for web application framework and Python for my core application.

I already have ZMQ being used internally for multiagent communication platform. If it is message queue, all I need to do is just connect to it, and send and receive data.

If it is a webservice, I need to freshly integrate the webservices. Again, what is the preferred method to create a webservice using Python?